# Code produces incorrect outcome

Tags: c, serial-port

The following code compiles in (Geany) and Runs.
--->

```
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <termios.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
//    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
//   tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);    /* sets Raw mode */

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void set_mincount(int fd, int mcount)
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = mcount ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;        /* half second timer */

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) < 0)
        printf("Error tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}


int main()
{
    char *portname = "/dev/ttyS0";
    int fd;
    int i;
    int wlen;

    fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", portname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    /*baudrate 2400, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B2400);
    //set_mincount(fd, 0);                /* set to pure timed read */

    unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D};
    write(fd,str,strlen(str));


    /* simple output */

/*
    wlen = write(fd, "*\n", 2);
    if (wlen != 2) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
    wlen = write(fd, "1\n", 2);
    if (wlen != 2) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
    wlen = write(fd, "8\n", 2);
    if (wlen != 2) {
        printf("Error from write: %d, %d\n", wlen, errno);
    }
*/
    tcdrain(fd);    /* delay for output */

    /* simple noncanonical input */

    do {
        unsigned char buf[80];
        int rdlen;

        rdlen = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
        if (rdlen > 0) {
#ifdef DISPLAY_STRING
            buf[rdlen] = 0;
            printf("Read %d: \"%s\"\n", rdlen, buf);
#else /* display hex */
            unsigned char   *p;
            printf("Read %d:", rdlen);
            for (p = buf; rdlen-- > 0; p++)
                printf(" 0x%x", *p);
            printf("\n");
#endif
        } else if (rdlen < 0) {
            printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));
        }
        /* repeat read to get full message */
    } while (i++ < 10);
}
```

<---
 I need the following output at the 'Serial Port' to invoke a certain outcome:
From the keyboard "* 1 8 cr" works perfectly under Windows (Turbo Basic) but not under my Code running under Linux (compiled by GCC):
-->

```
For " * 1 8 cr " (star one eight enter(cr)) the four "binary" "chars" required are:
*= binary 00101010
1= binary 00110001
8= binary 00111000
cr= binary 00001101
```

<--
  Unfortunately my code is not creating the correct output (Serial settings are believed to be set to (2400 N,8,1 with start and end bit) using 'termios' structure.
I have attached a old OscilloScope and there are bits being sent but I do not know how to capture them to check their correctness. 
  What is wrong with the Code?

Comment: That's hard code to read.  All the commented out code doesn't help.  What do you get sent instead of what you want?  Is all that code really necessary to produce your MCVE ([MCVE])?  I'm probably not equipped to help you much — you say "it compiles in (Geany)" but that doesn't mean a thing to me.

Comment: The code you copied from has been tested and works.  If you want to output the ASCII text string "*18\r"  (which you show in binary), then you need to be able to properly convert those binary values to hex when you initialize that array **str[]**.  IOW your array initialization statement `unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D};` is the root problem.  BTW why did you comment out the `tty.c_iflag = ...` statement?

Comment: Jonathan  What do you get sent instead of what you want?  I am unable to see what is being sent.  Maybe you can suggest how I can do that?

Comment: sawdust   "IOW your array initialization statement unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D}; is the root problem."  So what do you suggest?  "BTW why did you comment out the tty.c_iflag = ... statement?"  because I was unsure what those values did and thought they were not needed.  If I was an expert on this area I would be answering questions and not asking one.  I am looking for help.

Comment: *"I was unsure what those values did and thought they were not needed"* -- Since you're *"unsure"*, then you don't know if what you removed could be the reason why the code you copied no longer works.  Lucky for you, in this particular case it's not, but could cause issues when you perform reads.  *" If I was an expert on this area I would be answering questions and not asking one. I am looking for help."* -- Then learn to respond to questions without the attitude.  BTW your post is low quality.  It focuses on what you expect, and provides no description at all on what it currently does.

Comment: "BTW your post is low quality. It focuses on what you expect, and provides no description at all on what it currently does."  The program sends a bitstream but at 2400 baud I of course cannot tell what has been sent.  Given it does not turn on the light it is supposed to I assume that the Bits are not correct in some way.  A working Windows Turbo Basic program works on the same hardware properly.  I am not sure what the difference is, that is my problem.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returned the offset to the NUL byte, and offsets in C start with 0 and the array MUST be already NUL terminated,  so this expression: `strlen(str)` will return an unknown number (undefined behavior) suggest: `unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D, 0x00};` to fix the problem.

Comment: the function: `write()` and the function: `read()` return type is `ssize_t`, NOT `int`.  Of course, then this line: `printf("Read %d: \"%s\"\n", rdlen, buf);` needs to be: `printf("Read %lu: \"%s\"\n", rdlen, buf);`

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so this line: `printf("Error from read: %d: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));` should be: `fprintf( stderr, "Error from read: %lu: %s\n", rdlen, strerror(errno));`

Comment: note: the function: `strlen()` is expecting a parameter that is `const char *` NOT `unsigned char *`

Comment: the variable `wlen` is unused, seemingly due to the posted code's failure to check the returned value from the call to `write()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (in `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: user3629249  I have changed the code as you suggested.  Thank you:)

Comment: Sorry I did not recognize that all the answers was from you, user3629249.  I have made all the changes you have recommended and it compiles fine.  It will take awhile for me to check it as the target machine is elsewhere. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I was able to get this program working, The essential problem was trying to send HEX and I should have been sending ASCII values.  I have also incorporated many suggestions mentioned above to make the code 'better'.  The old line read:                                                                                unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D};

Comment: I was able to get this program working, The essential problem was trying to send HEX and I should have been sending ASCII values.  I have also incorporated many suggestions mentioned above to make the code 'better'.  The old line read:                                                                                unsigned char str[] = {0x56, 0x45, 0x52, 0x0D};     New line is                      const char str[] = {42, 49, 56, 13};    Thanks for all the help and I consider this problem solved.  Took to long to finish previous comment so I was unable to finish.  (Five minute limit).